# Why index accessing is faster than link access in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, jmh

I'm comparing the perfomance of contains method in ArrayList and LinkedList on a sequence of digits from 0 to 1000.

For both lists, I do a contains(400). ArrayList performance is always 3 times higher than LinkedList.
Comparison is made using JMH.

The ArrayList took 329,642 nanoseconds

The LinkedList took 945,881 nanoseconds

If both lists have O(n) performance of contains method, why is the LinkedList 3 times worse?

Comparation class:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
public class Comparation {
    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class MyState {
        private List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        private int iterations = 1000;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void setUp() {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                arrayList.add(i);
                linkedList.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean testLinkedListContains(MyState state) {
        return state.linkedList.contains(400);
    }
    @Benchmark
    public boolean testArrayListContains(MyState state) {
        return state.arrayList.contains(400);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Benchmark                           Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
Comparation.testArrayListContains   avgt   20  329,642 ± 20,709  ns/op
Comparation.testLinkedListContains  avgt   20  945,881 ± 43,621  ns/op
```

Comment: Because accessing the elements of an array by index is a ridiculously cheap operation. Using an `Iterator` (even a hidden one) involves an additional reference call. BTW, searching an array with [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) would be faster still (you aren't taking advantage of the fact that your lists are sorted).

Comment: ok, I understand that access by index is faster, but why exactly?

Comment: Because accessing an index is a single multiplication and addition. Following links involves deaccessing pointers until you get to the correct location.

Comment: Do you know what O(n) *means*? One could take 1ms and the other 1minute and they both could still be O(n) if for double the input size the time doubles to 2ms vs. 2minutes. And if one increases to 4ms while the other still increases 2minutes then the second one is better in terms of O-notation (n^2 vs n) but practically ill-suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArrayList, data is backed by an array whose elements are laid out contiguously in memory. So it is very fast to increment the iterator -> Just go to the next address in memory.

In LinkedList, this is not necessarily the case, the memory needn't be contiguous the elements may be randomly placed in memory, so going from one element to other is a bit slower.

Answer (score 2):

Your question: If both lists have O(n) performance of contains method, why is the LinkedList 3 times worse?

It is not against the rule of O(n) complexity, consider O(n) as something that describes an algorithm with linear time. Contrary to what you believe It does not mean all implementations of those algorithm have the same speed. It means time that they take is a linear function of their inputs, here  `ArrayList` is three times faster, but if you increase the number of element in `List` you can see `ArrayList` is still three time faster, and the time to iterate both of them grows as a liner function of the number of elements in `List`. So if you say `Arraylist` takes 2n  to execute that functionality and `LinkedList` takes 10000n to execute that functionality, you can say they both run in O(n).

Here you exactly came to this conclusion that `LikedList` is three times  worse, it means they have the same complexity O(n).

But If by increasing the number of input you find that it is not 3 times worse any more and it is getting 5 times worse or 30 times worse and this number grows based on the number of input(which is n), they don't have the same complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Very simply: different data structures have different performance trade-offs.

> https://dzone.com/articles/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs
>
> LinkedList is implemented as a double linked list. Its performance on
> add and remove is better than Arraylist, but worse on get and set
> methods.

In other words, if your motivation was to continuously *modify* the list, LinkedList might be a better choice.  But to simply *create* and *traverse* the list, ArrayList "wins".

To continue:

> As more elements are added to ArrayList, its size is increased
> dynamically. It's elements can be accessed directly by using the get
> and set methods, since ArrayList is essentially an array.
> ...
>
> Vector and ArrayList require space as more elements are added. Vector
> each time doubles its array size, while ArrayList grow 50% of its size
> each time.
> ...
>
> LinkedList, however, also implements Queue interface which adds more
> methods than ArrayList and Vector, such as offer(), peek(), poll(),
> etc.
> ...
>
> Note: The default initial capacity of an ArrayList is pretty
> small. It is a good habit to construct the ArrayList with a higher
> initial capacity. This can avoid the resizing cost.

In this case, an array is faster .. but less flexible.